# How to implement clicklistener on customadpter item in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to implement onClickListener on recyclerview item. Here is my *CustomAdapter.kt* Code.

```
package com.png.kotlinsample

/**
 * Created by admin on 13-08-2017.
 */
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView

/**
 * Created by prashant on 6/19/2017.
 */

class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>, val listener: (User) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    //this method is returning the view for each item in the list
        class MyAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    //this method is binding the data on the list
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(userList[position],listener)
    }

    //this method is giving the size of the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    //the class is hodling the list view
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(user: User, listener: (User) -> Unit) = with(itemView) {
            val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername) as TextView
            val textViewAddress  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress) as TextView
            textViewName.text = user.name
            textViewAddress.text = user.address
            setOnClickListener { listener(user) }
        }




    }
}
```

I want the click listener callback from my activity.

Comment: Do you want when you click in an item to get the User clicked object in the activity ?\

Answer (score 8):

```
class CustomAdapter(
    val userList: List<User>, 
    val listener: (User) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder = ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(userList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = userList.size

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            private val textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername)
            private val textViewAddress: TextView  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress)

        fun bindItems(user: User) = with(itemView) {
            textViewName.text = user.name
            textViewAddress.text = user.address
            setOnClickListener { listener(user) }
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
val adapter = CustomAdapter(userList) { user ->
    // do something with user on click
}
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: Just to clarify that the second part of the solution EpicPandaForce mentioned (val adapter = .... etc ) will need to go to the activity calling the adapter. Obvious probably but may help people that are now entering the Android world.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce A clean presentation.  But what if in the bindItems function you wanted to set OnClickListener on several elements of the ViewHolder and return the clicked *view* in addition to the 'user' class back to the adapter initialization in the activity so that different logic can be performed depending on the view returned?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @JoshJanvrin you could do that, but I think it's safer to then instead of passing a lambda callback, use an interface which has multiple methods, that way you won't need to know about exact view IDs to differentiate between the sources.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to send multiple parameters in listener. E.g., `class CustomAdapter(private val listener: (User, Int) -> Unit = {})`

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's do it in 3 steps

1- You define a interface with onClick method to be your callbacks
like this

```
 interface UserClickCallbacks {
    fun onUserClick(user: User)
}
```

2- Second in your adapter you add a click listener in the view holder with call the interface method like this

**EDIT**

```
class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>, private val userClickCallbacks: UserClickCallbacks) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    //this method is returning the view for each item in the list
    class MyAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    //this method is binding the data on the list
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textViewName.text = user.name
        holder.textViewAddress.text = user.address
    }

    //this method is giving the size of the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    //the class is hodling the list view
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
            val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername) 
            val textViewAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress) 

            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                userClickCallbacks.onUserClick(userList[adapterPosition])
            }


    }
}
```

3- At your activity you implement the the `UserClickCallbacks`  interface
 and override the `onUserClick()` method like this

```
class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity(), UserClickCallbacks  {

    // your activity code

    override fun onUserClick(user: User) {
        // but the user click event logic here 
        // This triggered when user in tha adapter clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the implementation of CustomAdapter with the constructor, how to add this callback

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add  `inner` to `ViewHolder` class or else you won't get access to `listener` object which is inside `Adapter` :

```
package com.niel.customview

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView

/**
 * Created by nileshdeokar on 12/03/2018.
 */
class MediaAdapter(private var mData: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MediaAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var listener: OnItemClickedListener

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.row_media, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        val model = mData[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mData.size
    }


    inner class ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, View.OnClickListener {
        var imageViewSq: ImageView

        constructor(itemView: View?) : super(itemView) {
            imageViewSq = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.imgSq)!!
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    fun setOnItemClickedListener(listener: OnItemClickedListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    interface OnItemClickedListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int) 
    }

}
```